# Troubles with AppCompat Theme whith pre Lollipop version on new AndroidStdio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

Yesterday, I have updated my AndroidStudio to version 2.2, and tried to run my progect. On 21 android ver. and hight he is all right, but on 19 ver some wigets(like TextInputLayout) looks "[crazy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbMnm.png)".

Wats wrong whith new AndroidStudia?